# PySide : Compute the amount of movement in both x and y axis since the previous call to the mouseMoveEvent function

Tags: python, pyside

I'm new to Pyside and I need to compute the amount of movement in both x and y axis since the previous call to the *mouseMoveEvent* function

The idea is to obtain the previous position of the mouse (A) and the current one (B). The we compute the vector starting from A and ending to B

My problem is the following : QMouseEvent doesn't have a lastPos() function, but a pos() one. Thus, I can't get the previous position of the mouse (The last recorded position is the position of the previous mouse event received by the view that created the event)

In Pygame this is known as *pygame.mouse.get_rel()*. How can I do this
?

Here is a sample code that prints the current position of the mouse when pressed and moved

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide import  QtGui

class Frame(QtGui.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, (width, height)):
        super(Frame, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle('Frame')
        self.show()
        self.loop()

    def loop(self):
        while 1:
            self.update()
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Get the current position of the mouse
        x, y = event.x(), event.y()
        print (x, y)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame((500, 500))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this without `PySide`, which I currently can't install, but I *think* you want something like this (read `NOTE1` and `NOTE2`):

```
import sys
from PySide import  QtGui

class Frame(QtGui.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, (width, height)):
        super(Frame, self).__init__()

        # NOTE1: indicate if mouse was clicked
        self.clicked= False

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setWindowTitle('Frame')
        self.show()
        self.loop()

    def loop(self):
        while 1:
            self.update()
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Get the current position of the mouse
        x, y = event.x(), event.y()
        print (x, y)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # NOTE 2: track clicks, not movements
        if self.clicked:
            # calculate vector
            vector = ((self.x, self.y,), (event.x(), event.y(),))
            print "vector: %s" % str(vector)
            self.clicked = False
            return vector
        # set vector start
        self.x = event.x()
        self.y = event.y()
        self.clicked = True
        print "vector set to start from: (%d,%d)" % (self.x, self.y)
        return None

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame((500, 500))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you can set a vector from first click to second, vector starts on each mouse click. This probably has some errors, but the idea is clear. If you want mouse to track movement and not clicks, apply the same principles (storing last position in the subclass, set flag to see if vector should be calculated...) to the `mouseMoveEvent`.

I'll test it later when I'm with my pc.